# Календарь на PHP

Tags: php, календарь

Передо мной стоит задача реализации календаря на PHP. Так как из языков я ориентируюсь только в JavaScript, а с PHP знаком только с синтаксисом, долго искал в просторах интернета как реализовать данную задачу. Вроде бы получилось и кажется работает, но у меня есть некоторые сомнения, что с этим можно идти дальше.
Прошу разбирающихся в PHP глянуть на мой код и дать по-возможности рекомендации для дальнейшего апгрейда.

```
<?php
  $dayofmonth = date('t');
  $day_count = 1;
  $num = 0;

  for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
  {
    $dayofweek = date('w',
                      mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), $day_count, date('Y')));
    $dayofweek = $dayofweek - 1;

    if($dayofweek == -1) $dayofweek = 6;
    if($dayofweek == $i)
    {
      $week[$num][$i] = $day_count;
      $day_count++;
    }
    else
    {
      $week[$num][$i] = "";
    }
  }
  while(true)
  {
    $num++;

    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
    {
      $week[$num][$i] = $day_count;
      $day_count++;

      if($day_count > $dayofmonth) break;
    }

    if($day_count > $dayofmonth) break;
  }
  echo "<table border=1>";

  for($i = 0; $i < count($week); $i++)
  {
    echo "<tr>";

    for($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++)
    {
      if(!empty($week[$i][$j]))
      {
        if($j == 5 || $j == 6) 
             echo "<td><font color=red>".$week[$i][$j]."</font></td>";
        else echo "<td>".$week[$i][$j]."</td>";
      }
      else echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  } 
  echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: непонятно зачем столько циклов, вот вам два совета wile(true) мягко говоря плохо выглядит.

Comment: "реализации календаря" - опишите на русском языке, что должен делать ваш код. Так будет легче получить какие-то осмысленные рекомендации.

Comment: @svgrafov Необходимо было (используя HTML) создать календарь который будет соответствовать календарю операционной системы (актуальная дата, выходные дни и т. д. ). Вроде ничего сложного, если бы я больше ориентировался в данном языке, я бы данный вопрос не задавал, но увы.

Comment: Вопрос вообще не про программирование, а про поставленную задачу. К примеру, календарь в моей ОС показывает текущее время, дату, список дней в месяце с подписанными днями недели. Насколько это похоже на то, что вам нужно?

Comment: @svgrafov Ок. Код рабочий, в этом я убедился. К вам, если вы разбираетесь в PHP такой вопрос. Можно ли его сократить существенно? Все таки в мире на данный момент правит оптимизация. Я и сам с этим разберусь как только руки дойдут (много других задач на JS, мозги пухнут).

Comment: Если нужно добавить к концу и началу календаря начало и конец недель, находящиеся в других месяцах - маякните.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так, например, можно получить массив `$calendar`, ключи которого - дни месяца, а значения - порядковые номера дней недели. Выделен текущий день. С логикой отображения, думаю, без труда разберётесь.

```
$today = new \DateTimeImmutable();
$daysInMonth = (int)$today->format('t');
$day = new \DateTimeImmutable('first day of this month');
$calendar = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++){
    $calendar[$i]['weekday'] = $day->format('w');
    if ($day->format('d') == $today->format('d')){
        $calendar[$i]['today'] = true;
    }
    $day = $day->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

[DateTimeImmutable](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetimeimmutable.php).